# ASPxUploadControl FileUploadComplete get file name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Is there an easy way to grab the file name?

I'm trying something like this with no luck ;/

```
 Protected Sub ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs) Handles ASPxUploadControl1.FileUploadComplete

        Dim fileInfo As New FileInfo(e.UploadedFile As String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to grab the file name?

Yes

```
Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename)
```

Here's a complete sample where only excel files are allowed:

```
Private Shared allowedExtensions As New List(Of String)(New String() {".xls", ".xlsx"})

Private ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) ASPxUploadControl1.FileUploadComplete
    If e.state = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Success Then
        Dim fileExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(e.filename)
        If allowedExtensions.Contains(fileExt) Then
            Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(e.filename)
            Dim appDir As String = Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath
            Dim subDir As String = My.Settings.UploadSubDirectory
            Dim path As String = appDir & subDir & fileName
            ASPxUploadControl1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path)
            ASPxUploadControl1.FileContent.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (includes example) exists [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxUploadControlASPxUploadControl_FileUploadCompletetopic).

The example given is in C#, but the idea is the same.

Example from documentation:

```
protected void ASPxUploadControl1_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e) {
        if (e.IsValid) {
            ASPxUploadControl1.PostedFile.SaveAs(MapPath("Images/" + 
                   ASPxUploadControl1.PostedFile.FileName));
        }
    }
```